Multiple HandlerStack in same application causing high response time
One of my backend uses HandlerStack::create(), so I can add to it a custom middleware that is used by all clients. So far, so good.
Recently, I needed to add a new Middleware::retry(), but this need to be to a specific client. So I created a new HandlerStack to add this behaviour only to the client that need this.
After that, my overall response time get 5x slower, specifically the pretranser time (even in the clients with the default HandlerStack).
What was my approach:

first, I imagined that could be my retry logic. So I added retry middleware to default client and keep just one handlerStack. Everything is fine
Well, so there's nothing with retry logic, so let's create two default HandlerStack. Slowing down response time
Lets create two HandlerStack with retry. Slowing down response time.

If anyone faced something similar, let me know.
I'm using php 7.4 and "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.9.1"
Obs: I certified that the increase in response time had nothing to do with the retry taking place. In fact, I increased timeout to a high number and put logs into it.
The response time should not be affected.
